# PlayStation 4 friends to xbox friends

Tags: ps4, xbox-one

Is it possible to add someone on xbox 1 s to PlayStation 4 friends. I have already tried sending them a friend request but it went to someone with that name on my PlayStation 4.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, your PS4 friends have to also be on the Playstation network.  Both of these consoles have their own separate networks.  You can't connect Microsoft and Playstation accounts.

Comment: Thanks i had this problem for a long  time.